# Computation of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[5]{2}]\otimes _\mathbb Q\mathbb Q[\sqrt[5]{2}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $K=\mathbb Q[\sqrt[5]{2}]$; I  must compute $K\otimes _\mathbb QK$. Looking at what we have done in the lecture, I would go in this direction: $\mathbb Q[x]\to \mathbb Q[x]\to \frac{\mathbb Q[x]}{(x^2-5)}\to 0$  is a right exact sequence, where $\mathbb Q[x]\to \mathbb Q[x]:f(x)\mapsto (x^2-5)f(x)$ and the other homomorphism is the projection. If I apply to the sequence the tensor $-\otimes _\mathbb QK$, I should obtain that $K\otimes _\mathbb QK$ is isomorphic to $\frac {K[x]}{(x^2-5)}$. Is this the final result (if is correct?) Or should I find a way  to write it as the quotient of $\mathbb Q[x]$ (or $\mathbb Q[x,y]$ maybe) by some ideal?

Comment: $x^5-2$ in place of $x^2-5$ (or $\sqrt{5}$ in place of $\sqrt[5]{2}$); you may want to decompose the result into a direct sum of fields, i.e. to factor $x^5-2$ to irreducibles in $K[x]$

Comment: I see that in $K$ the polynomial $x^5-2$ is not irreducible anymore, so the result is isomorphic to $K[X]/(x-\sqrt[5]{2})(x+\sqrt[5]{2})$. However these two polynomial are not coprime in $K$, so I wouldn't know how to traduce the quotient in a product of fields

Comment: They **are** coprime in $K$: their difference are a nonzero constant, so you have a Bezout relation.